# CSS not loading in Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My CSS file is located here: `/Areas/Car/Views/Shared/CSS/css.css`. I reference it in my code like this:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("/Areas/Car/Views/Shared/CSS/css.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However, C# is throwing a 404 error for that link.

I've tried adding a context.MapRoute:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "CSS",
    "/Areas/Car/Views/Shared/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Car", action = "CSS", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
};
```

And then accessing it with `/Car/CSS/css.css` (and all the variations I can think of)

But I am still getting the same error. If, however, I reference a different css file - not in Areas - it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should not put your css files inside `Views` directory. By default, in MVC this directory is not accessible directly via url. (That's why you cannot access your views directly, but only through controller action.)

Consider using `Content` directory at the root of the web app. You could create a separate directory there for you Area.

Alternatively, create a `Content` directory in your Area, for example `/Areas/Car/Content/css.css`.